# How to disable WiFi straight from the Action Center?

Tags: wifi, 8.1, action-center

The new Action Center in Windows Phone 8.1 is great, I can set WiFi on/off as one of the quick actions and enable it with just one tap. However, when I try to disable WiFi from the Action Center, it takes me to the Settings page where I have to toggle it off manually. This is annoying because it takes more time, especially if I try to do this from the lock screen because then I have to type in my PIN first to unlock the phone.

Is it possible to have the Action Center disable WiFi as soon as I tap the WiFi quick action tile?

Comment: I think there's no such feature in the Windows Phone 8.1 also....the Wifi in the action center now is once you pressed, then it redirect you into the Wifi setting only...Annoying for me too...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think this is by design. It can be because you can set how long do you want your WiFi to be turned off before it turns itself automatically on. There are options in *Turn WiFi back on* dropdown menu:

- in 1 hour,
- in 4 hours,
- in 1 day,
- near my favorite places and
- manually.

You can notice that this behavior is different when you are turning WiFi manually ON - there is no redirection to settings page - WiFi is just turned on and automatically connecting to some network.

Maybe there will be some update in future with option to change this behavior (i.e. set the default option when to turn wifi back on).

If it is more comfortable (well, I doubt it) you can use Cortana for turning off WiFi (just say *Turn off WiFi* to her) - she will do that with no additional questions ;)

Comment: "*You can notice that this behavior is different when you are turning WiFi manually ON*" Indeed, hence my question. It kind of defeats the point of having a *quick* action. Using Cortana isn't really any quicker, but thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: I don't see "near my favorite places" on my Lumia 925, what phone do you have?

Comment: This would be caused by active Cortana, I think (geofencing feature is one of Cortana-specifics).

Answer (score 0):

No, even I find it annoying but I guess the motive behind keeping because there are more settings in WiFi like "WiFi Sense" and "Manage Wifi connections".